# Could not find adapter type bigquery

Tags: dbt

Having trouble running dbt today... encountered this error message and cannot debug the issue. I did not have this issue yesterday and have not changed anything since.

Installed dbt with Homebrew

```
Running with dbt=0.18.0
dbt version: 0.18.0
...
Configuration:
  profiles.yml file [ERROR invalid]
  dbt_project.yml file [OK found and valid]
Profile loading failed for the following reason:
Runtime Error
  Credentials in profile "dandelion-bq", target "dev" invalid: Runtime Error
    Could not find adapter type bigquery!
```

Comment: Hey @jayoub -- what's the command you ran to install dbt? And, what is the output of `which dbt`?

Comment: Hey @ConnorMcArthur, I've since fixed this error... looks like it was an issue with my anaconda install. there was a dbt core package installed and i think that led to the conflict; not entirely sure how that package was installed

Comment: I'd also highly recommend upgrading to 0.18.1 - latest stable.

Answer (score 8):

Probably you installed a plugin or another version of dbt-core, try:

```sh
dbt --version
```

It should list the plugins installed, guess in your case there is no bigquery there:

```sh
dbt --version
installed version: 0.19.0
   latest version: 1.0.0

Your version of dbt is out of date! You can find instructions for upgrading here:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/installation

Plugins:
  - postgres: 0.19.0
  - bigquery: 0.19.0
```

Install it, with pip or pip3

```sh
pip install dbt-bigquery
```

Same applies for any other [plugin/adapter](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/available-adapters) when you get the error `Credentials in profile <profile>, target <target> invalid: Runtime Error Could not find adapter type <plugin>!`